# Suggestions for DevDays speaker theme songs

Tags: discussion, fun, devdays, devdays-2009

Every hero needs a theme song, so what should our heroic speakers at the DevDays events make their entrance to?

Comment: Hurray! You got yourself a Friday question!

Comment: @gnovice: I almost posted a friday afternoon question asking for ideas for a friday afternoon question.

Comment: @TheTXI: That would have been too meta for even Meta to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, Jon Skeet needs to use ["Get Low"](http://www.lyrics007.com/Lil%27%20Jon%20&%20the%20Eastside%20Boyz%20Lyrics/Get%20Low%20Lyrics.html) from Lil' Jon. For God's sake, they spell "Jon" the same way and he even says "skeet" in the song!

Comment: Awwww skeet skeet skeet skeet skeet

Comment: **Yea-ah!**

Comment: **What!? OKay!**

Comment: Looks like "someone" was desperate to get their Citizen Patrol badge? ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Joel**:

- *Another one bites the dust* by **Queen** (Read his blog to understand)

**Jeff**:

- Star Wars Intro or the Ewoks Theme from Episode 6.

Answer (score 1):

**Jon Skeet**:

- *We Are The Champions* by **Queen** (there should also be a StackOverflow Championship Belt involved somehow as well).

Comment: Go with the Jonathan Coulton version though: http://www.jonathancoulton.com/songdetails/We%20Will%20Rock%20You-We%20Are%20the%20Champions

Answer (score 1):

**Jon Skeet:**

I think I ought to come in to ["Skeet Surfing"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-jqEj1Hvnc) from the movie ["Top Secret!"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088286/)

The first couple of lines from the Portal theme would do quite nicely too :)

Or a rewrite of the theme of "Into the woods" to be "Onto the Stack" given my penchant for Sondheim...

**Jeff:**

"Tell me why I don't like Mondays" but with "Mondays" replaced by "PHP" each time.